# Typescript check existance of value shortcut

Tags: typescript

I am iterating a array by finding it's existence. is there any short cut with `Typescript` with the same?

here is my traditional approach:

```
data = data &&
    data.map(item => {
      return {
        ...item,
        ComponentName: this.rowData.componentsData.find(i => i.ComponentId === item.ComponentId).Components
      };
    });
```

i tried like this: ( adding ? mark )

```
data = data?.map(item => {
      return {
        ...item,
        ComponentName: this.rowData.componentsData.find(i => i.ComponentId === item.ComponentId).Components
      };
    });
```

But found the error. what is the correct way in typescript?

example error :

```
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

  251 |       }
  252 |     } else {
> 253 |       const validOptLangCombinations = optArr.map(item => `${item.CourseId}-${item.Component.LanguageCode}`);
      |                                               ^
  254 |       loopOverOptions &&
  255 |         loopOverOptions.forEach(op => {
```

example code :

```
 const validOptLangCombinations = optArr.map(item => `${item.CourseId}-${item.Component.LanguageCode}`);
```

my solution : ( no error thrown )

```
 const validOptLangCombinations = optArr && optArr.map(item => `${item.CourseId}-${item.Component.LanguageCode}`);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Modify the array to add compoundName? What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: If I remove the existence check, I am getting an error as ` TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` in unit testing

Comment: This is really not helpful. Kindly paste a reproducible code with the rest of the data and a stack trace of the error if possible.

Comment: @Akhil - check my updates

Comment: Whatever you are doing is fine. You can even use the optional chaining operator(`?`) but the result of the `optArr.map` function would be undefined that you would have to handle somewhere else.

Comment: @Akhil - if I use `?` still getting an error as ` error TS1005: ':' expected.` what is mean? what is the correct way to use?

Comment: You could do `optArr?.map(v => ...)`. But then if `optArr` is `undefined`, this expression returns `undefined` and thus `validOptLangCombinations` will be `undefined`.

Comment: so using `?` is not valid. but `optArr && optArr.map` is valid then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236668/discussion-between-akhil-and-user2024080).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several approaches to this issue. One way is the way you have described by using optional chaining. The reason why this can result in an error is that everything will immediately stop running whenever some expression is `null` or `undefined`.

```
data = data?.map(item => {
      return {
        ...item,
        ComponentName: this.rowData.componentsData.find(i => i.ComponentId === item.ComponentId).Components
      };
    });
```

This optional chaining is the same as the following code snippet:

```
data =
  data === null ||
  data === undefined ?
  undefined : data?.map(item => {
      return {
        ...item,
        ComponentName: this.rowData.componentsData.find(i => i.ComponentId === item.ComponentId).Components
      };
    });
```

A better more secure way of doing is, is by checking before executing if it is not `null` nor `undefined`.

```
data = data && data.map(item => {
      return {
        ...item,
        ComponentName: this.rowData.componentsData.find(i => i.ComponentId === item.ComponentId).Components
      };
    });
```

When you are absolutely sure that this variable cannot be `null` or `undefined`, you can add the non-null assertion operator. That's how the TypeScript compiler won't complain about null issues:

```
data = data!.map(item => {
      return {
        ...item,
        ComponentName: this.rowData.componentsData.find(i => i.ComponentId === item.ComponentId).Components
      };
    });
```

The next awesome way to have default values, if it is `null` or `undefined`, is the nullish coalescing. This is how you can use the default value `[]` for your variable.

```
data = data?.map(item => {
      return {
        ...item,
        ComponentName: this.rowData.componentsData.find(i => i.ComponentId === item.ComponentId).Components
      };
    }) ?? [];
```